# How to save errors through observer on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am creating a module to save the errors response of shipping method and payment method on checkout page through observer

Like when its say user submit his/her billing/shipping and they get :

> the shipping method is currently unavailable

save this error into table. 
and on when they 
"place order" and get the error :

> Gateway error: Unable to read response, or response is empty

save it also in db

my code is config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Paras_Ordertrack>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Paras_Ordertrack>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Paras_Ordertrack_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveorder</method>
                    </checkout_order>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
             <sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Paras_Ordertrack_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderPlace</method>
                    </checkout_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>        
        </events>
    </frontend>
    --------
    --------
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Paras_Ordertrack_Model_Observer
{

    public function saveorder($observer)
    {
        // how to get shipping response error here ??
    }



    public function orderPlace($observer){      

        // how to get payment method response error here ??
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of observing `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`, you want to observe `sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure`. This event is fired when there is an error. Then, you'll want to use PHP's `Exception` class to get the previously thrown exception with the `getPrevious()` method.

On the first one, you're currently observing the `preDispatch` method of the controller. At that point, the controller action won't have been run, so you'll want to change that event to another that will happen after the error occurs.

Please let me know if you have any questions!